# Problems when linking my main output library with my test executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, msbuild

I'm building a "framework" library which one I'm trying to integrate Google Tests. It's a pretty small library, that at the end gives me a `.so` or `.dll` file.

When I was starting to tests my library, I found a configuration (details below) that works fine on my `CMakeFile` at my linux environment. But when I try to run the same project using a `MSBuild` for `MSVC14`, it gives me a link error

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '..\src\Debug\foobar.lib'`

I'm thinking that my cmake is guessing the lib name wrong (`foobar.lib` instead of `foobar.dll`), but I couldn't find why nor how to fix it.

Also, I don't know if this is really the best way for me testing this. What I want is a way to test the whole framework (initializing, creating stuffs, checking returns etc..) without a `main.cpp` file, and meanwhile start to create the unit tests.

So, my question is.. What am I doing wrong that at the Windows environment the linker does not find the `foobar` lib built by `src/CMakeLists.txt`? (I checked, and the lib is created in "src/Debug/foobar.dll", same dir that appears at the error, and works fine)

Also, is my method so wrong that windows just don't wanna deal with? lol I mean, it's wrong to do something like I'm trying to do? It's not that I do not want to make unit tests, which I'll be doing soon, but I really like to build and try my lib without using any external exec binary before I starting to do that.

Thanks!

OBS:

- My google tests is working fine both in linux and windows;
- I can run the test FooA if I remove the FooBar test, which is linking to `foobar` lib.
- Using my linux environment this configuration works perfectly.

**Update:**

As @vre suggested, I found the macro `__declspec(dllexport)` and put it before my `FooBar` class name and the compilation passed, but it crashes when I run and throws this warning when compiling:

```
warning C4251: 'FooBar::_impl': class 'std::unique_ptr<FooBar::FooBarImpl,
std::default_delete<_Ty>>' needs to have dll-interface to be used by clients of class 'FooBar'
```

That's because I have a PImp implementation of the `FooBar` class. So, I have this:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) FooBar
{
    ...

    private:
        class FooBarImpl;
        std::unique_ptr<FooBarImpl> _impl;
}
```

I don't really know what it means yet. Trying to find out why it crashes.

---

My project has this file tree:

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
|   ├── FooBar.hpp
├── src
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── FooBar.cpp
│   ├── FooA
│   │   └── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── FooB
│   │   └── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── FooC
│       └── CMakeLists.txt
└── test
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── FooBar
    │   └── FooBarTest.hpp
    ├── FooA
    │   ├── FakeBar.hpp
    │   ├── FooATest.hpp
    │   └── mockObj.hpp
```

My main `CMakeLists.txt` is like this:

```
...
set(FOOBAR_INCLUDE "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/FooBar.hpp")

# Include src main CMakeLists
add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

# Include tests if enabled
if (test)
 add_subdirectory("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/test")
endif ()
```

My `src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
...
set(FOOBAR_SOURCES "FooBar.cpp")

# Build
add_library(foobar SHARED ${FOOBAR_SOURCES} ${FOOBAR_INCLUDE})

# Links the library with components.
target_link_libraries(foobar FooA FooB FooC)
```

And my `test/CMakeLists.txt` is something like this:

```
enable_testing()

# Include directories used for testing.
include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src"
                    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
                    "FooA/"
                    "FooBar/")

# Include the files for testing.
set(INCLUDE_TESTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/FooA/FooA.cpp"
                  "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/FooA/Bar.cpp")

# Include the test source files.
set(TEST_SOURCES  "main.cpp"
                  "FooBar/JepluTest.hpp"
                  "FooA/FakeBar.hpp"
                  "FooA/FooATest.hpp")

# Build
add_executable(foobar-test ${TEST_SOURCES} ${INCLUDE_TESTS})

# Links the library with components. (HERE IS WHERE OCCURS THE PROBLEM)
target_link_libraries(foobar-test gtest foobar)

# Not really important right now
add_test(NAME foobar-test COMMAND foobar-test)
```

Comment: Do you export any functions from the DLL? Otherwise no import library foobar.lib is created.

Comment: @vre My DLL works fine. I was testing it using an executable linked with it. I did not use that macros `__export` if it's that what you mean. Should I use that?

Comment: @vre okay, if I put that the build "works", but when I execute it crashes. Trying to identify why. Tnks!

Comment: Don't know about the `__export` macro but I was talking about `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` macros on windows platform. See `GenerateExportHeader` function in `CMake`.

Comment: @vre That's the one that I put, and works! But gives me a warning and does not solve my problem. The executable is still crashing. I updated my answer with it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformulating and enhancing my previous comments:

You need to export symbols from the DLL on Windows otherwise no import library is created, and that's what MSBuild is complaining about.

First you should add to your FooBar.hpp header the following construct:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    #ifdef FOOBARLIB_EXPORTS
        #define FOOBARLIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define FOOBARLIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define FOOBARLIB_API
#endif
```

Later mark your classes, functions and symbols to be exported as follows:

```
void FOOBARLIB_API foobar(char*)
{
}
```

In your `CMakeLists.txt` after creating the shared library target `foobar` add the line:

```
target_compile_definitions(foobar PRIVATE FOOBARLIB_EXPORTS)
```

EDIT:
As @vre commented, these `CMake` properties are also needed because Windows does not load a `DLL` located in another folder, causing a crash when it tries to run the executable. So, when a `DLL` is build and the `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable is set, the output library goes to the same directory as the test `.exe` file.

```
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```

Comment: It works! The only problem now is that the test need to find the .dll at the same directory, but this is another problem, I guess. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: The build process separates the build artifacts of different targets in different directories. But on windows a DLL is only found in directories that are added to the `PATH` environment variable or in the directory of the executable. For that reason common output directories are frequently used in CMake. `set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)` Doing so the DLL can be found easily by your test.